# SOAP Service returning result on .Net Core but not in .Net Framework (Classic)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, soap, https

I am calling an external service from my code.

https://api.escapia.com/wsdl/EVRNContentService.wsdl

I am able to get response in project I made in ASP.Net Core but couldn't get response for the same service in .Net Framework 4.7.2

What could be the reason, that, its working on one, and not on other?

PS: The code, service urls, everything is same in both projects.